# Is it possible to upload only the first 10 rows of a CSV file using MySQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: php, mysql, load, local

Is it possible to only upload the first 10 rows of a CSV file using MySQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE? I tried using LIMIT but it’s not working.

Here is my PHP script:

```
    $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).
         "' INTO TABLE branches
              FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
              LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
              IGNORE 1 LINES                  
              (
                Name,
                Address_Line_1, 
                City, 
                State, 
                Country_Code,
                Postal_Code, 
                Main_Phone, 
                Google_Places_Link, 
                Custom_Directory_1, 
                Custom_Directory_2, 
                Custom_Directory_3,  
                business_id,
                username
              ) SET branches.business_id=(".$this->business_id."), branches.username=('".$this->username."') LIMIT 0,10  
              ";
```

Comment: using LOAD DATA .. NO, other ways, yes

Comment: Run this first `head -n 11 myfile.sql > myfile_first_11_lines.sql` and upload the shorter file?

Answer (score 3):

The solution below provides a LIMIT-style behavior for `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  Use `IGNORE n LINES` and set to the *total rows - whatever small number* you want to test.

This does not save on file scans, isn't elegant, and works backwards (literally).  But for tables of moderate length less than a million rows, for me it's useful for testing. (It may work for much larger tables, but I have not had occasion to test that.)

For example, the last 20 rows of a large table with 101,773 rows would be

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/temp/input/datafile.csv'
    -- IGNORE
    INTO TABLE `mytable`
    
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    FIELDS  TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\b'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 101753 LINES
```

Answer (score 0):

By last mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var
        [, col_name_or_user_var] ...)]
    [SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT},
        [, col_name={expr | DEFAULT}] ...]
```

there is no way/command which can do it what you want.